# How to read the contents from a file in an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to read a file which has name value pair on a remote server. As per the requirement I need to shell into the remote server, read the file, and then grep for the values. Example:

```
/domain/srvr/primary = ABC
/host/DEF/second = DEF
/host/XYZ/second = XYZ
/host/GHI/second = GHI

:
:
:
```

Now I want to read this file and make an array of all secondary servers (ex: DEF, XYZ, GHI) but I am getting nil value.

```rb
primary = @ssh.exec!("cd /home/dir; grep 'srvr/primary' #{filename} | awk '{print $3}'")

secondary = @ssh.exec!("cd /home/dir; grep '\<host.*second\>' #{filename} | awk '{print $3}'")`
```

It prints the primary server name properly but returns nil for secondary servers array. I tried to use `split("\n")` but errors out by saying `undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass`.

Need help in getting all the secondary servers in an array.

Comment: You may be getting ahead of yourself when you say you'd 'grep for the values'. It might be better to say you want to extract certain values, making no assumptions about the methods that would be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```rb
file_contents.
  split("\n").
  map {|line| line.split(" = ")  }.
  find_all {|pair| pair[0] =~ /second$/  }.
  map(&:last)
```

and probably get file contents with `cat` or downloading the file through ssh. If in the same server just use `File.read`.

If you can only use bash or just prefer to, you can use

```
grep -p "^\/host.*second" path/to/file | cut -d" " -f 3
```

The `-p` option will enable perl regexp syntax on `grep` which will give you all the capabilities you want to search through the file. Then `cut` will split each string by the delimiter `-d` ang get the field of 1 based index `-f`. In this case `string = server`, so `server` is on the third field.

Comment: Thank you for all your replies. As suggested by @the Tin Man, I used Net::SCP to copy the file in memory and then find the strings which I needed. Below is my working piece of code: `require 'net/scp' 

 data = nil

 Net::SCP::start("hostname", "username", :password => "password") do |scp|
        data = scp.download!("/remote/file/path")
 end
  data =  data.split("\n").grep(/\bsecond\b/).map{ |l| l.split.last }

 data.each {|host| puts host + ' is secondary server'}
`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to do the work on the remote host, you can simplify the task and only grab the data and process it locally. You can use [Net::SCP](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-scp) ([docs](http://net-ssh.github.io/scp/v1/api/classes/Net/SCP.html)), [Net::FTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html) or [Net::SFTP](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-sftp) to easily retrieve the data.

I'd use something like this to grab the desired data once the text has been received:

```
data = <<EOT
/domain/srvr/primary = ABC
/host/DEF/second = DEF
/host/XYZ/second = XYZ
/host/GHI/second = GHI
EOT

data.split("\n").grep(/\bsecond\b/).map{ |l| l.split.last }
# => ["DEF", "XYZ", "GHI"]
```

or:

```
data.split("\n").grep(/\bsecond\b/).map{ |l| l[/= (\S+)/, 1] }
# => ["DEF", "XYZ", "GHI"]
```

or:

```
data.split("\n").grep(/\bsecond\b/).map{ |l| l.rstrip[/\S+$/] }
# => ["DEF", "XYZ", "GHI"]
```

Just to make it more interesting:

```
require 'fruity'

data = <<EOT
/domain/srvr/primary = ABC
/host/DEF/second = DEF
/host/XYZ/second = XYZ
/host/GHI/second = GHI
EOT

compare do
  p1 { data.split("\n").grep(/\bsecond\b/).map{ |l| l[/= (\S+)/, 1]  } }
  p2 { data.split("\n").grep(/\bsecond\b/).map{ |l| l.rstrip[/\S+$/] } }
  p3 { data.split("\n").grep(/\bsecond\b/).map{ |l| l.rstrip[/\S+$/] } }
end
# >> Running each test 256 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> p1 is faster than p2 by 3.9x ± 0.01
# >> p2 is similar to p3
```

Comment: How about `data.scan(/(?<=\/second = ).*$/)` or `data.scan(/\/second = \K.*$/)`?

Comment: Run that against the entire file or against a single line? Against the entire file encounters the scalability problems of slurping. Against a single line it returns an array of a single value that then has to be flattened or indexed or shifted to get at that value. `scan` has its place but it can result in more code needed to clean up the result.

Comment: I meant that to be applied to the entire file, as the OP said the file would be read before being processed. If it were read line-by-line, I'd suggest `line[r]` with the same regex `r`.